# Javascript handle refreshing with button

Tags: javascript

I am quite new to Javascript. I am trying to implement a button that controls whether a page is refreshing or not. However, it doesnt work (clicking on the button triggers some actions like alert etc, but doesnt change the label button and doesnt stop refreshing the page).

Can you tell me where I went wrong, please? Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Message log</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body onload="JavaScript:timedRefresh(5000);">

    <button id="bRefresh" onclick="refreshMode()">Stop refreshing</button>

    some content...

</body>
</html>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
    <!--
        var refresh = 1;

        function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
            if(refresh == 1) {
                setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
            }       
        }

        function refreshMode() {
            if(refresh == 1) {
                var refresh = 2;
                document.getElementById("bRefresh").value="Start refreshing";
            } else {
                var refresh = 1;
                document.getElementById("bRefresh").value="Stop refreshing";
            }       
        };
    //   -->
</script>
```

Comment: this wont work at all..Because once page starts reloading javascript will stop excecuting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look like below,

```
        var refresh = 1;
        var timedInterval= null;
        function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
            if(refresh == 1) {
                timedInterval = setInterval(function() { location.reload(true); },timeoutPeriod);
            }       
        }

        function refreshMode() {
            if(refresh === 1) {
                 refresh = 2;
                 clearInterval(timedInterval);
                 document.getElementById("bRefresh").innerHTML="Start refreshing";
            } else {
                 refresh = 1;
                 timedRefresh(5000);
                document.getElementById("bRefresh").innerHTML="Stop refreshing";
            }     
            //document.getElementById("bRefresh").innerHTML="Start refreshing";  
        };
```

Use setInterval instead of setTimeout for repeated tasks

you declared refresh variable three times so your buttons value doesn't change.

innerHTML instead of value should be used to change the Buttons text.

To stop use clearInterval as above.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="bRefresh">Stop refreshing</button>

var button = document.getElementById("bRefresh");
var refresh = 1;
var timeoutPeriod = 5000;
var id;

function timedRefresh() {
    if (refresh == 1) {
        window.location.reload(true);
    }
}

function refreshMode() {
    if (refresh == 1) {
        clearInterval(id);
        refresh = 2;
        button.textContent = "Start refreshing";
    } else {
        id = setInterval(timedRefresh, timeoutPeriod);
        refresh = 1;
        button.textContent = "Stop refreshing";
    }
};

button.addEventListener("click", refreshMode, false);

id = setInterval(timedRefresh, timeoutPeriod);
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/KqjYw/)

Answer (score 0):

use innerHTML for [supporting IE < 9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Node.textContent)

```
var button = document.getElementById("bRefresh");
var refresh = 1;

function refreshMode() {
    if (refresh == 1) {
        refresh = 2;
        button.innerHTML = "Start refreshing";
    } else {
        vrefresh = 1;
        button.innerHTML = "Stop refreshing";
    }
};

button.addEventListener("click", refreshMode, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

On the load of the body, `prepareRefresh()` function check the value `refresh` (set to 1) and start refresh the page with a timeout.
You should launch the refresh, and just before refresh, you had to check the `refresh` value. Because in the first case, `location.reload` don't care about modification of `refresh`. Check the `refresh` value at the end of the timeout

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    <!--
        var refresh = 1;

        function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
            if(refresh == 1) {
                setTimeout("refreshPage();",timeoutPeriod);
            }       
        }

        function refreshPage ()
        {
          if(refresh == 1) {
                setTimeout("location.reload(true);", 0);
            }  
        }

        function refreshMode() {
            if(refresh == 1) {
                refresh = 2;
                document.getElementById("bRefresh").innerHTML="Start refreshing";
            } else {
                refresh = 1;
                document.getElementById("bRefresh").innerHTML="Stop refreshing";
            }       
        };
    //   -->
</script>
```